# do samplling on text file in js

Tags: javascript, fetch, sampling

i wanted to do sampling on the text data output fetched from an api as the data is huge , also the size is dynamic everytime.

**let response = await fetch(urll, options);**

**let testdata = await response.text()**

**let str = testdata.split('\n');**

here the test data size is huge so i wanted to do sampling and then use the sample data for further.
please help!!
now str stores 10000000 of lines and i cannot plot a graph outta 10000000 of data points so i need to do sampling over here

this is what i found is this kind of approach is fine

`cat yourfile.txt | perl -ne 'print if (rand() < 0.000001)'`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; you want to grab random lines, e.g., you've split your input text on `\n` and take a sample of those based on a function?

Comment: yes @DaveNewton please chk i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Read from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file), you can use awk command to select 'from line' -> 'to line'

```
awk 'NR >= 57890000 && NR <= 57890010' /path/to/file
```

OR

```
 awk 'NR < 57890000 { next } { print } NR == 57890010 { exit }' /path/to/file
```

This way, you can add parameters to the fetch url to retreive what you want, then you have to split the text in a temp array to add in the big one with an offset index witch is the request 'from line' number.

```
bigArray = [];
const from = 200000;
const to = 250000;
let response = await fetch('urll?from='+from+'&to='+to, options);
let testdata = await response.text();  
let lines = testdata.split('\n');
let idx = 0;
lines.forEach(line => {
  bigArray[from + idx] = line;
  idx++;
}
......
```

but regardless of your lines size, this can take a hudge amount of memory, so maybe you can delete some indexes, for example before "from line" - 100000 and after "to line" + 100000 and reload data when you shift the graph rendered values.

Comment: GEThttp://localhost/urll?from=200000&to=250000 its giving me 404 error while fetching

Comment: I don't know how your server responds to requests, You ask for sampling, but you also have to know how to create a server witch will respond to your request. For example to handle php file witch will execute the awk command then send back to the javascript fetch API. You also can use nodeJS, Python script, .... It's up to you!